# The charge of the electron before measurement

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Knowing that electrons do not have a definite position before they are being measured, how can their charge be described before the measurement? Where is the charge? Does it make sense to talk about their charge before measurement?

Answer (score 4):

The charge and mass of an electron are natural constants. All electrons have the same charge. The position of an electron is not constant at all. Where is the charge? Wherever the electron is. The statement that a particle "does not have a definite position" before being measured of course means that the position of its charge is similarly undefined, but the charge is still very well defined.

Comment: Good answer. Concise and correct

Comment: it seems to me that saying that the charge of an electron is a natural constant is just a reformulation of the fact that we know the charge of the electron without measuring it, which was the question asked.